# Why is my Application Pool stopping on first request after modifying Advanced Settings from a remote IIS client?

Tags: iis-10

This started happening recently. After changing a couple of settings in the Advanced Settings window through a remote IIS client, the application pool automatically stops and I can't restart it without stopping again instantly or after its first web request.

What's interesting is that after getting that issue, I reenter the Identity credentials being used in the same Advanced Settings window, and the Application Pool works again.

There are no messages in the Event viewer.

The only plausible explanation is that saving the settings through a remote client somehow messes up with the Identity used. If I change the same settings directly on the server, I don't get this issue.

Has anyone had this happen before?

Comment: `After changing a couple of settings in the Advanced Settings` what settings have you changed?

Comment: The underlying mechanism of IIS remote management is not very well documented, so unless you talk to someone inside Microsoft who has access to the relevant code and docs, nobody else can help me and tell the cause. Contact Microsoft support via https://support.microsoft.com and open a support case if you are in a hurry to resolve it.

Comment: @samwu  Start Mode from OnDemand to AlwaysRunning and Idle Time-out in Process Model from 20 to 60. But I could be changing just the Start Mode back from AlwaysRunning to OnDemand while the Application Pool is active and I get the same problem of it shutting down until I reenter the Identity credentials. This behavior only happens while managing from the remote client.

Comment: @samwu Correction...  It seems that it only stops and I have to reenter the Identity credentials when changing a configuration within the Process Model group, if I change just the Start Mode from AlwaysRunning to OnDemand, the AppPool remains active with no issues.

Comment: There are many reasons why an application pool can stop automatically, usually the Event Log should contain this information. what information did you check in the Event viewer?