# Remote IIS administration of Application Pools show a blank Advanced Settings window

Tags: iis-10

I'm currently setting up a Windows 11 machine. After enabling the remote administration console. I'm able to open the remote IIS server (v.10) and work with any configuration.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to open the Advanced Settings for any application pool, I get a blank screen

[Blank Advanced Settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10J4N.png)

I have another computer with the same settings but that one has Windows 10 and I can remotely manage the same IIS without problems. (Well, except one small issue which popped up recently but I don't think they're related - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808914/why-is-my-application-pool-stopping-on-first-request-after-modifying-advanced-se))

Comment: It's likely that they are related to each other, but the misery won't be easily analyzed without further knowledge on IIS Manager internals. Thus, Stack Overflow is not a good place to look for answers.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.